# Can structure entries have their own entries?

Tags: sections, entry-slug

I have a bunch of categories within a section on my website, but I want each category item within that section to be able to have an additional slug. For example:

mywebsite.com/categories/category/information (information being the additional slug)

Is this possible with Craft?

Comment: What do you mean by "external link"? If you have a category group (and not just made a section and put your categories as entries) you can enable "Categories in this group have their own URLs" in your category group settings. https://craftcms.com/docs/categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Following your comment, and if I understand well, you already are using a URL for the categories, but want to create kind of a subpage "information" for them. It is a bit more complicated but it can be achieved. What you can do is create a route, either from the control panel or the `config/routes.php` file in `craft/config`. It may be easier to do it from the control panel first. If you go to Settings > Routes and click on "New route" you can enter the following information:

[image: New route popup]

It will create a new URI endpoint for the "information" pages that you want and map them to a `_information.html` template in the "categories" folder.

You can then create `_information.html` template and retrieve your category using the following code:

```
{% set category = craft.categories({ group: 'categoryName', slug: craft.request.segments[1] }) %}
```

Assuming the handle of your category is `categoryName` of course.
`craft.request.segments` is an array containing all parts of your URI, starting from 0. Thus, the second part of the URI, which is the selected category's slug, is stored in `craft.request.segments[1]`.
The variable `category` will then contain all the fields assigned to the category that you want to display in the information page.

---

It is possible and quite easy to do in Craft.
You can create a new text field named "External link" for example, and assign it to the category.

To do that, go to Settings > Categories > {Name of your category} and select the "Field layout" tab. You can then assign the "External link" field to the category like you would for a section.

You can now edit your categories and add the external link for each one of them.

Comment: What I meant by the external link was to have an additional slug onto of my category item, so it would add an additional page. So 'information' being that additional page which I could add fields to. Can this still be done with categories?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!